# Kernel panic recurring

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, kernel-panic

I keep getting the following kernel panic. Can anyone help me, please? As a test I have just change HDD to SSD and update memory from 2 GB to 8 GB. All said to be compatible with Mac. Upgraded OS X to Mountain Lion. Clean install from USB stick. Still the kernel panic happens a lot. What seems to be wrong?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  1537 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          1


Tue May 21 21:49:37 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801d0b7e95): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80f8b8be80, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff80f8b8be80, CR3: 0x000000001fd46000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660
RAX: 0x0000000000b672b1, RBX: 0x0000011445eda085, RCX: 0xffffff802f6c2000, RDX: 0xffffff802f6ce800
RSP: 0xffffff80f8b8bdd8, RBP: 0x0000000000000000, RSI: 0x0000000000b672b1, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0xffffff801d601ef0, R9:  0x7ffffffffffffffe, R10: 0x0000000000008611, R11: 0x00000000ffffff80
R12: 0x7fffffffffffffff, R13: 0x000003b8e5dab7ad, R14: 0xffffff80f8b5c148, R15: 0x0000000000000005
RFL: 0x0000000000010096, RIP: 0xffffff80f8b8be80, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80f8b8be80, Error code: 0x0000000000000011, Fault CPU: 0x0 Kernel NX fault

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80f8b8ba70 : 0xffffff801d01d626 
Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.26 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.47f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E4D3136464400
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E4D3136464400
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.3f3 11349, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SH103S3120G, 120,03 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0x24400000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0x26500000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0237, 0x04600000 / 3
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x04500000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 / 2
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8213, 0x06110000 / 3
```

Comment: You might want to check the check if you just changed it. There is probably a faulty one.

Comment: Check what? If its the ram and SSD they are completely new and OK. Same error happened over and over with old HDD and ram. Also that ran on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Support has a page on [Kernel Panics](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3742), including troubleshooting repeated KPs.

In my experience, they most often have to do with hardware changes / external mounting and unmounting, but of course YMMV.

Comment: Is it possible to read anything from the kernel panic above?

Comment: Not unless you are a real adept at reading logs. Easier to examine what actions you might have taken, in conjunction with using Apple's info as linked.

Answer (score 0):

Its a probable RAM issue. Take out the RAM, clean them up, and put it again in the slots. It also happens when one of the RAM gets faulty, or is not properly attached.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with some general advice and follow the links at the bottom of the answer:

- [What is a Kernel Panic and what does it mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean)