# Kernel Panic Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, hardware, bluetooth, kernel-panic, kernel-extensions

I have been receiving kernel panics a few times in the past few months, but each time I have noticed it is when I am connected to the internet through Bluetooth PAN to my iPhone. Most recently, the panic happened while opening pages through handoff on my iPhone.

Are there any thoughts on what is causing this? More specifically, if I do not have any kernel extensions installed (as per log) except ones that start com.apple.... (Except nosleep, which doesn't seem to be involved at all, as I wasn't using it) does that suggest that I have a hardware problem?

> Anonymous UUID:       7D31B270-795B-5E3F-F5FD-2970176B122D
>
> Tue Sep  8 16:07:41 2015
>
> *** Panic Report *** panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801596cffd): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.32: expected
>   0xc0ffee4c12a6d854 but found 0xffffff8034697500, bits changed
>   0x3f0011cc26cfad54, at offset 24 of 32 in element 0xffffff8034697260,
>   cookies 0x3f0011cc26cfa554
>   0x53521d97cffa037"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.30.5/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:496
>   Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff82266d3a40 :
>   0xffffff801592bda1  0xffffff82266d3ac0 : 0xffffff801596cffd 
>   0xffffff82266d3b30 : 0xffffff801596ca71  0xffffff82266d3b70 :
>   0xffffff801596b8b7  0xffffff82266d3ca0 : 0xffffff8015934601 
>   0xffffff82266d3cd0 : 0xffffff8015dc877c  0xffffff82266d3d10 :
>   0xffffff8015e168a1  0xffffff82266d3e20 : 0xffffff8015e2777b 
>   0xffffff82266d3ee0 : 0xffffff8015e248ba  0xffffff82266d3f50 :
>   0xffffff8015e4bc56  0xffffff82266d3fb0 : 0xffffff8015a35376
>
> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: bnepd
>
> Mac OS version: 14E46
>
> Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT
>   2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID:
>   E3C26B2F-8B97-3F1D-B193-690F7E34F830 Kernel slide:
>   0x0000000015600000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8015800000
>   __HIB  text base: 0xffffff8015700000 System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)
>
> System uptime in nanoseconds: 91866682380872 last loaded kext at
>   83284562272452: com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient    3.7.5 (addr
>   0xffffff7f980fc000, size 36864) last unloaded kext at 83423328691470:
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7f980f4000, size
>   16384) loaded kexts: com.protech.NoSleep  1.4.0
>   com.apple.filesystems.afpfs   11.0 com.apple.nke.asp-tcp  8.0.0
>   com.apple.filesystems.smbfs   3.0.1 com.apple.filesystems.autofs  3.0
>   com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC    1.70
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager  4.3.5f8
>   com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.19.6
>   com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.2.0d4
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim  1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 272.18.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient  3.6.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU  2.0.7d0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet    1.0.1
>   com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess    1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHV  1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface 5.36.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.5f8
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight   170.7.4
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.2.12
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP   2.0.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics 10.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul    10.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons    240.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader   3.5.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard   240.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub  705.4.2
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless   1.0.0d1
>   com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib   1.0.0
>   com.apple.BootCache   36 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter  404
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage    2.7.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort    3.1.2
>   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 930.37.3
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI 710.4.11
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHPET    1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC  3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
>   com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 161 com.apple.security.quarantine   3
>   com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet    8
>   com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword   1.0
>   com.apple.kext.triggers   1.0 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
>   com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib  1.15
>   com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>   com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily   5.9.1d7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily  1.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily    11
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.5f8
>   com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.3.5f8
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient   705.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController   272.18.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily   272.18.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 203.3 com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9
>   com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.13d1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 97.4 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport  2.4.1
>   com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl  3.10.24
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2  156.16
>   com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily  2.4.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.7.5
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.7.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.7.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch   245.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver    705.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 705.4.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite    705.4.9
>   com.apple.driver.CoreStorage  471.30.1
>   com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily  2.7.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter  4.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily  4.0.6
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter   2.0.2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI  3.1.7
>   com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily   4.2.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 730.60
>   com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient    1.0.1b8
>   com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily    3.2
>   com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily   720.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
>   com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime  2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
>   com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
>   com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5
>   com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager   1.0
>   com.apple.driver.DiskImages   397 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
>   com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily    31
>   com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30
>   com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform    3.1 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
>   com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily  1.4 com.apple.kec.Libm  1
>   com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto  1.0

Comment: Please post the kernel panic log.

Comment: @SillyWilly Done.

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: @n1000 Macbook Pro retina (mid 2014). IPhone 5s. Osx 10.10.4 and ios 8.3

Comment: General advice on troubleshooting kernel panics is here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean Since the posting, are there more panics?