# What is Causing the Kernel Panic

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

I've been having an issue where my computer will randomly shut down and give me the panic report saying that your computer restarted because of a problem. I took it to the apple store they ran a diagnostic, and all they did was wipe my OS. It is still having the same problem so I recently just erased my whole system in reinstalled my OS X 2 more times, and I still seem to be having the issue. I have reset the smc and nvram multiple times. I've ran the disk utility first aid multiple times. Can some interpret this for me who knows how to read panic reports to see what is causing this issue.

**Crash Log 1**

```
Anonymous UUID:       F09B71C3-8AB1-702D-2793-2ED9EB989AE9

Thu Jan 14 09:52:20 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff802f9d155a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802fb4615b, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000000, CR3: 0x0000000031729001, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff913e34bb80, RCX: 0x0000000000001000, RDX: 0x0000000000001000
RSP: 0xffffff913e34b9a0, RBP: 0xffffff913e34ba90, RSI: 0x0000000000000000, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x0000000000001001, R9:  0x0000000000001000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x000000000000002e
R12: 0xffffff8044477690, R13: 0xffffff913e34bae8, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x000000000000a6a0
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff802fb4615b, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000000, Error code: 0x0000000000000002, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff913e34b630 : 0xffffff802f8de792 
0xffffff913e34b6b0 : 0xffffff802f9d155a 
0xffffff913e34b890 : 0xffffff802f9ef233 
0xffffff913e34b8b0 : 0xffffff80 2fb4615b 
0xffffff913e34ba90 : 0xffffff802fd13062 
0xffffff913e34bb20 : 0xffffff802fb1d3fa 
0xffffff913e34bc10 : 0xffffff802fd9863f 
0xffffff913e34bcc0 : 0xffffff802fd96f57 
0xffffff913e34bf60 : 0xffffff802fe29ac1 
0xffffff913e34bfb0 : 0xffffff802f9efa36 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd

Mac OS version:
15C50

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-  3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 17EA3101-D2E4-31BF-BDA9-931F51049F93
Kernel slide:     0x000000002f600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802f800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802f700000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 37078588484
last loaded kext at 5545924897: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr    0xffffff7fb20f4000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.21
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.8
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    203.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0A, 4 processors, Intel    Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,    0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF),     Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.94.136.1a1)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.3f4 16616, 3 services, 19 devices, 1 incoming serial    ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM256E, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

**Crash Log 2**

```
Anonymous UUID:       F09B71C3-8AB1-702D-2793-2ED9EB989AE9

Thu Jan 14 11:52:19 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff802dbd155a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff802db89a5e, type 6=invalid opcode, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x000000010f09d5f3, CR3: 0x000000002967604d, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x00000000313436f0, RBX: 0xffffff813133b578, RCX: 0xffffff802e2ed178, RDX: 0x0000000000000010
RSP: 0xffffff813133b3d0, RBP: 0xffffff813133b410, RSI: 0x0000000000000007, RDI: 0xffffff802e22ce90
R8:  0x0000000000003000, R9:  0xffffff802e2ed178, R10: 0x00000000382ce8e6, R11: 0x0000000000000003
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0xffffff80396c9340, R14: 0x0000000000000003, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff802db89a5e, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0x000000010f09d5f3, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 1

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff813133b060 : 0xffffff802dade792 
0xffffff813133b0e0 : 0xffffff802dbd155a 
0xffffff813133b2c0 : 0xffffff802dbef233 
0xffffff813133b2e0 : 0xffffff802db89a5e 
0xffffff813133b410 : 0xffffff802db7d279 
0xffffff813133b7a0 : 0xffffff802dfda7c3 
0xffffff813133b7e0 : 0xffffff802dd44b5b 
0xffffff813133b890 : 0xffffff802df199e5 
0xffffff813133b990 : 0xffffff802e0220c4 
0xffffff813133baa0 : 0xffffff802db40a88 
0xffffff813133baf0 : 0xffffff802db3fb73 
0xffffff813133bb30 : 0xffffff802db4b440 
0xffffff813133bd00 : 0xffffff802db50e5e 
0xffffff813133bf20 : 0xffffff802dbd1b4f 
0xffffff813133bfb0 : 0xffffff802dbef145 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: ManagedClient

Mac OS version:
15C50

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.2.0: Fri Nov 13 19:56:56 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.20.55~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 17EA3101-D2E4-31BF-BDA9-931F51049F93
Kernel slide:     0x000000002d800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802da00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802d900000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16942579922
last loaded kext at 7766792260: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7fb02f4000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.21
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup    10.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.8
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    203.14
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

**Crash Log 3** (I edited this out - it was the same as crash 2 - you can see the system uptime in nanoseconds for a quick check before pasting in the third :-)

The hardware is a retina 2012 MacBook Pro and has all software updates and EFI updates applied.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34319/discussion-on-question-by-chris-grizzy-what-is-causing-the-kernel-panic).

Answer (score 4):

Please keep in mind this is a guess, based on the 3 logs you provided and your description that you've wiped the OS several times without a change in issue behavior.

I noticed that all 3 logs show a crash when loading the same kext:

```
last loaded kext at 7766792260: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70 (addr 0xffffff7fb02f4000, size 32768)
```

This may indicate an issue with audio from your motherboard, assuming your not using any external audio interface. Another potential cause is an issue with RAM.

The machine certainly seems to have a hardware issue of some sort.  A practial solution for most HW techs at this point, would be to install test RAM in the machine and run the machine through its paces to see if the issue can be reproduced.  Depending on the frequency of crashes this can take a few hours, or days.  Since your RAM is soldered on the logic board, that would be swapped in case of a RAM issue.

Comment: +1 for the RAM - I would run memory tests or take it back to Apple / phone Apple Support to ask them about running a RAM diagnostic remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is things are crashing really quickly. It's far easier to collect the 10 to 20 logs you'll need to make an armchair guess at what's happening.

In the mean time, consider disconnecting all peripherals and keeping a log of what you're changing in case you can stumble upon the cause (or at least correlation.)

I don't have much to add here that hasn't been said on another thread:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/199744/5472

We'll probably need to see a dozen log files (or post them somewhere like github gist) to have any chance of making progress. Apple will eventually have a better solution than "reinstall" the OS as that's simply one of the first things they can change before escalating the actual crash reports with data to engineering. I would contact Apple and ask them how many reports they want collected before you bring it back to them for more detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error on my MacBookPro (same model as your's - 10,1).  Is it running hot?  Check the aluminum part of the case just above the function keys on your keyboard.  Mine was almost too hot to touch.  The crashes happened more frequently/faster when I was using dual monitors (one external via Lightening port).  The MBP screen would just go blank, the keyboard was still lit - the lights were on but nobody home.  I'd let it cool for about a half-hour and start again.  There is a known issue with the video.  Mine started crashing in mid-2014 and it sat for almost a year.  Fortunately I had a spare MacBook from my job.  Then I had a little spare time and searched for solutions to my problem.  I stumbled upon this:

https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

I made an appointment at local Apple store, took it in (on a Sunday afternoon).  They verified that the issues with my MacBookPro were those covered by the program, sent it to Texas for repair, and I had it back on Friday (5-day turn-around!).  After so much time not having my MacBook working, I was seriously thinking about changing course - trade iPhone for Android and get a Windows notebook - due to the poor support.  I'm still not happy about the time it took Apple to admit to the problem, but I still think Apple is the best platform for what I need.

I backed up everything and removed confidential/proprietary docs during the small periods between crashes.  When I got it back, the hard drive had not been touched - all was just as I left it.  I think what they did was just replace the motherboard.  Even the aluminum case had not been replaced.  One note: I still have some heat issues.  I'm pretty sure the replacement motherboard was the same model I previously had (not re-engineered to fix the problem).