# Recurring kernel panic when waking from sleep — can anyone tell me what this report means?

Tags: sleep-wake, crash, kernel-panic

Hello — I'm experiencing kernel panics every single time my Mid-2012 MacBook Pro (2.3 GHz, Intel i7) wakes from sleep. Running El Capitan 10.11.3. I look at the reports, but they are entirely greek to me.

Can anyone can tell me what this report means, or if there are any clues here as to what's going on? Here's the latest report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       F777AFFC-FEBB-9A03-D8D1-F4E6D51DC8A9

Mon Jan 25 10:56:05 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff8005fd255a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800645c4c5, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007000005b2000, CR3: 0x0000000009896000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff80398c3fa0, RCX: 0xffffff81a57cb000, RDX: 0x0000000000014500
RSP: 0xffffff81f012bdb0, RBP: 0xffffff81f012bdc0, RSI: 0xffffff80398c30a0, RDI: 0xffffff802469e820
R8:  0xffffffffffffffec, R9:  0x0000000002282200, R10: 0x318476a608586030, R11: 0x0000000000000014
R12: 0xffffff81f012be01, R13: 0xffffff8039dd8c00, R14: 0xffffff80246bf040, R15: 0xffffff80398c30a0
RFL: 0x0000000000010293, RIP: 0xffffff800645c4c5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007000005b2000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81c4da3c50 : 0xffffff8005edf792 
0xffffff81c4da3cd0 : 0xffffff8005fd255a 
0xffffff81c4da3eb0 : 0xffffff8005ff0233 
0xffffff81c4da3ed0 : 0xffffff800645c4c5 
0xffffff81f012bdc0 : 0xffffff800645ce3c 
0xffffff81f012bdf0 : 0xffffff80064397b6 
0xffffff81f012be20 : 0xffffff8006494d0a 
0xffffff81f012be90 : 0xffffff8006493a4b 
0xffffff81f012bef0 : 0xffffff8006490bfe 
0xffffff81f012bf30 : 0xffffff800648e516 
0xffffff81f012bf70 : 0xffffff80064944cc 
0xffffff81f012bfb0 : 0xffffff8005fccf77 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
15D21

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.3.0: Thu Dec 10 18:40:58 PST 2015; root:xnu-3248.30.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DECC9F02-27D7-31F0-9599-A9EF2873902C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005d00000
System model name: MacBookPro9,1 (Mac-4B7AC7E43945597E)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 198439896007612
last loaded kext at 43752992991306: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f891b9000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 149070907056764: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver   1.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f89175000, size 184320)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.0
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.20.22
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.51.3
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.GeForce   10.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.12
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1020.17.1a1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.51.3
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.0.1
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.0.8
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.51.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

Comment: A crash 55 hours after boot might be hard to pin down. Are you looking for [general advice](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean?)?

Comment: @bmike If his computer is crashing as a result of a kernel panic, I doubt very much he cares about what it is, but rather about making it stop crashing.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard I prefer to not assume - you might be right but I didn't want to edit your answer to cover what a panic log means.

Comment: Just some insight as to what could be happening, if that's possible. I don;t know what any of the above means, or if it contains any clues. I cleared the log files last night and let it sleep, same thing this morning. 

Here's a link to the latest log, if you or anyone has the time to check it out: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2e707t2bfyyxphp/AADPXGF9TBHVkwiHlR2ZrDoYa?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to tell from that what's causing the crash, but seeing as SoundFlower hasn't been updated since 2014, and certainly hasn't been updated for El Capitan, my money's on SoundFlower being the culprit here. Try uninstalling it, or just moving its kext out of "/Library/Extensions/" and restarting.  See if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks William. I have a video capture app I use that wants it, unfortunately. Will try your suggestions regardless. Thanks again!

Comment: I updated Soundflower last night to a new version that's supposed to be compatible with El Capitan. The software using it isn't running usually, I only use it when I need to create screen capture videos. Could it still be causing an issue even though the software isn't launched?

Comment: @JoeNatoli Wow... I've had Soundflower's kext installed for so long, I completely forgot I had it! I haven't needed it in a few years... If the Soundflower kext is causing an issue in your case, it would seem more probable that it is the application utilizing it than the kext. I've certainly never experience a panic from the kext itself.

Comment: That's what I figured. The app only runs when I'm doing a screencast, which isn't that often — and I never experience a crash/restart when running it. Always after the laptop goes to sleep, even with no applications open or running. Completely stumped.

Comment: @JoeNatoli Sometimes, kernel panics can be caused by hardware problems. I'd try restarting into the Apple Hardware Test, by holding down "d" while booting, and run some tests. The extended test takes awhile, but is likely to uncover any hardware problems that may exist. If you have a couple hours, it may be worth running it once.