# Help Diagnosing this Kernel Panic Log

Tags: kernel-panic

So... I've had about 10 kernel panics in the last 3 days... and I honestly have no idea what is causing them... if someone is able to diagnose... here's the latest...

```
Anonymous UUID:       C9FC42BF-2CCB-328A-00CB-DD3CC0E1A136

Tue Oct  1 14:21:41 2019

*** Panic Report ***
Panic(CPU 0, time 377541062089644): NMIPI for spinlock acquisition timeout, spinlock: 0xffffff80826aec90, spinlock owner: 0xffffff807d4f3000, current_thread: 0xffffff807d4f3000, spinlock_owner_cpu: 0x0
RAX: 0xffffff8006e821b8, RBX: 0xffffff8052d59400, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x000000000001575f
RSP: 0xffffff838e1c7e10, RBP: 0xffffff838e1c7e20, RSI: 0xffffff8052d59400, RDI: 0xffffff8052cee140
R8:  0x000000006e44c281, R9:  0xffffff805290f0e8, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0xffffff805290f000, R13: 0xfffea8a0df1b2714, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0xffffff8052c07f00
RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff8006a5ddfd, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff838e1c7cb0 : 0xffffff80064db00b 
0xffffff838e1c7d10 : 0xffffff800635be47 
0xffffff838e1c7e20 : 0xffffff7f8752b411 
0xffffff838e1c7e40 : 0xffffff8006a5db7d 
0xffffff838e1c7e90 : 0xffffff8006a82293 
0xffffff838e1c7ef0 : 0xffffff7f89f84af6 
0xffffff838e1c7f30 : 0xffffff7f88b1edb0 
0xffffff838e1c7f50 : 0xffffff7f88b27b79 
0xffffff838e1c7f70 : 0xffffff80064db05b 
0xffffff838e1c7fd0 : 0xffffff800635bced 
0xffffffa3f751bec0 : 0xffffff80063ed885 
0xffffffa3f751bf40 : 0xffffff80063ed425 
0xffffffa3f751bfa0 : 0xffffff800635b0ce 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(6.1)[F5A615E4-D5B8-3E06-A29F-F79EA07A15EF]@0xffffff7f88b17000->0xffffff7f88bb2fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[3E8E9870-2E41-33F6-ACBF-35DDC08F22B5]@0xffffff7f86e71000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BFDEB8D4-50FE-3DDB-87B7-F6A504393830]@0xffffff7f86c95000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[0A338AA2-4958-384B-9941-59A96A38C42C]@0xffffff7f86e7a000
         com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC(1.7)[11588E04-78B2-398C-9651-CFE08B2003C5]@0xffffff7f89f83000->0xffffff7f89f85fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[BFDEB8D4-50FE-3DDB-87B7-F6A504393830]@0xffffff7f86c95000
         com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI(1.2)[35B704AE-7145-3F4D-9717-069DBB4B9647]@0xffffff7f87514000->0xffffff7f8755afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[3E8E9870-2E41-33F6-ACBF-35DDC08F22B5]@0xffffff7f86e71000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[BD06015A-414D-34DF-BE36-7B9034D7360D]@0xffffff7f86eaa000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[FA45971B-83C4-3569-901E-749A36177C94]@0xffffff7f86ea2000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
18G95

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006100000
System model name: MacPro6,1 (Mac-F60DEB81FF30ACF6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 377541062154650
last loaded kext at 2275393101303: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  3.3.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8a8c8000, size 442368)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.2.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.2.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.2.30
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.2.30
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.2
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.4
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   2.1.1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.12
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter  107
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMGPUPowerControl  3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    2.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  408.250.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBODD    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDisplays   380
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.6.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.3
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   201
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2450.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2440.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.4
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.2
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   2.1.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.12
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.3.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.66
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.5
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.9
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.6
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff80064d08dc): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff80826aec90, lock owner thread=0xffffff807d4f3000, current_thread: 0xffffff8056c3b520, lock owner active on CPU 0x0, current owner: 0xffffff807d4f3000, time: 377541062196063"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.271.2/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:494
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3f8c0b880 : 0xffffff80063ae6ed 
0xffffffa3f8c0b8d0 : 0xffffff80064ea185 
0xffffffa3f8c0b910 : 0xffffff80064db8ba 
0xffffffa3f8c0b980 : 0xffffff800635bb40 
0xffffffa3f8c0b9a0 : 0xffffff80063ae107 
0xffffffa3f8c0bac0 : 0xffffff80063adf53 
0xffffffa3f8c0bb30 : 0xffffff80064d08dc 
0xffffffa3f8c0bb70 : 0xffffff80068a7985 
0xffffffa3f8c0bbe0 : 0xffffff80068a70fc 
0xffffffa3f8c0bd60 : 0xffffff80068aaf46 
0xffffffa3f8c0bdb0 : 0xffffff7f88a59acc 
0xffffffa3f8c0be20 : 0xffffff7f88a599c1 
0xffffffa3f8c0beb0 : 0xffffff80068754ae 
0xffffffa3f8c0bf00 : 0xffffff8006874be8 
0xffffffa3f8c0bf60 : 0xffffff800687473f 
0xffffffa3f8c0bfa0 : 0xffffff800635b0ce 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.kec.pthread(1.0)[B29EB8C4-AB00-31D9-98C9-ECC62761A605]@0xffffff7f88a58000->0xffffff7f88a61fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

EOF
Model: MacPro6,1, BootROM 132.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5, 3.7 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.20f18
Graphics: kHW_AMDFireProD500Item, AMD FirePro D500, spdisplays_pcie_device, 3 GB
Graphics: kHW_AMDFireProD500Item, AMD FirePro D500, spdisplays_pcie_device, 3 GB
Memory Module: DIMM1, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1866 MHz, 0x802C, 0x33364A534632473732505A2D3147394E3120
Memory Module: DIMM2, 16 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1866 MHz, 0x802C, 0x33364A534632473732505A2D3147394E3120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x135), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en2
PCI Card: AMD FirePro D500, Display Controller, Slot-2
PCI Card: AMD FirePro D500, Display Controller, Slot-1
PCI Card: Apple 57761-B0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@73,0,0
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, IEEE 1394 Open HCI, Thunderbolt@72,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, USB Open Host Controller, Thunderbolt@71,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, USB Open Host Controller, Thunderbolt@71,0,1
PCI Card: pci12d8,400f, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Thunderbolt@71,0,2
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, IEEE 1394 Open HCI, Thunderbolt@80,0,0
PCI Card: Apple 57761-B0, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@81,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, USB Open Host Controller, Thunderbolt@79,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, USB Open Host Controller, Thunderbolt@79,0,1
PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@85,0,0
PCI Card: pci12d8,400f, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Thunderbolt@79,0,2
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500.28 GB
Serial ATA Device: ST2000LM007-1R8174, 2 TB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Display)
USB Device: Apple Thunderbolt Display
USB Device: ePass FIDO
USB Device: Display Audio
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Display)
USB Device: Apple Thunderbolt Display
USB Device: Display Audio
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: Jabra SPEAK 510 USB
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: MT1887
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt Display, Apple Inc., 1, 26.2
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2
```

Comment: [Here is a good resource](https://objective-see.com/blog/blog_0x27.html) to help you read kernal panics.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199737/313842 do update if you narrow it down!