# 2018 Mac Mini getting crashing under load

Tags: crash, mac-mini, kernel-panic

I just bought a brand-new 2018 Mac mini (i5, 32GB RAM, 256GB SSD) and it has started Kernel Panicking (I assume? it stops outputting to the display and the fan gets really loud for a second, the LED stays on and I have to hold it for 10 seconds to restart it). This pretty much just happens under load, which is a real shame because I need to use it under load.

I would attach the crash log, but it appears that it's too long for StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh no! If you upload the entire crash file to a gist - link to it and @ me and we can upload the relevant parts. Most of the steps you’ll take are already covered, so perhaps these will help with either formatting or how to proceed (like disconnect everything) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199737/what-is-a-kernel-panic-and-what-does-it-mean

Comment: @bmike https://gist.github.com/At0micMac/d00b174cd4b02fbd5e6291f19c0ede5e

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue.  Are you still able to return for a replacement?

Comment: You should be able to take it back to wherever you bought it and ask them to test it.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your SMC?

Comment: @Allan thanks for your help. What makes it seem like a hardware issue? Just today it crashed again (right after I made a backup) and now it doesn't display anything and after about 15 seconds the fan ramps up then the LED & fan shut down. I've already made an appointment at the Apple Store.

Comment: From the logs, it indicates “CPU throttling.”  This should not happen on a “brand new” machine.  Personally, I wouldn’t waste time diagnosing but get a replacement (obviously if within the return window)